# Balanced Binary Tree logic

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

the problem was to determine if a given tree(with A as root) is balanced or not.
i wrote this piece of code. It's failing on one test case.
What's wrong with the logic?

```
int depth(TreeNode* root){
    if (root==NULL) return 0;
    else return max(depth(root->left),depth(root->right))+1;
}
int Solution::isBalanced(TreeNode* A) {
    if(A==NULL) return 1;
    if((abs(depth(A->left)-depth(A->right)))>1) return 0;
    else {
        isBalanced(A->left);
        isBalanced(A->right);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the failing test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're throwing away the results of the recursive calls in your else clause.  Try something like this:

```
if((abs(depth(A->left) - depth(A->right))) <= 1 && isBalanced(A->left) && isBalanced(A->right)) {
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```